# Hosting React App on Fire base having problem with routing

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I just start learning for a month. I built a react Application which is host on Firebase and using cloud function for API and Firestore for DB.
The problem I encounter is when I published my react app, when I tried to navigate through my application by manually typing URL, the URL will return 404 and If I refresh the page in one of sub-page, it returns 404 as well. The routing only worked If I navigate from the index page.

I have done some research, most of suggestions would be creating server side routing. It is possible to achieve my goal without using SSR?Is it because the routing config I did or I didnt do to cause this? FYI, it works when It run locally. 
My routing is a little bit rubbish since I didnt design it really well.

**App.jsx**

```
function App() {
    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Switch>
                <Route path="/invitation" exact component={Home} />
                <Route path="/" component={DashBoard} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    );
}
```

inside the Dashboard component, I have sub routes.

```
 render() {
  return (
        <div className="container">
            <div className="mask" />
            <NavBar user={this.state.user} logOut={this.logOut} />
            <div className="container-body">
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path="/schedule"
                        exact
                        component={Schedule}
                        user={this.state.user}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/betting"
                        exact
                        component={Betting}
                        props={this.state}
                    />
                    <Route path="/login" exact component={Login} props={this.state} />
                    <Route
                        path="/register"
                        exact
                        component={Register}
                        props={this.state}
                    />
                    <Route path="/teams" exact component={Teams} props={this.state} />
                    <Route path="/addteam" component={AddTeam} props={this.state} />
                    <Route path="/teams/:id" component={TeamPage} props={this.state} 
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/administrator"
                        component={Administrator}
                        props={this.state}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/unauthorized"
                        exact
                        component={Page403}
                        props={this.state}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path="/notfound"
                        exact
                        component={Page404}
                        props={this.state}
                    />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </div>
  );
}
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
 "functions": {
   "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint"
    ],
   "source": "functions"
 },
"hosting": {
"public": "built",
"ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
]
 }
}
```

So this is basically What I have done with routing. I didn't do any more for the routing config. Is it anything wrong with my routing setup? and also How can I fix the route problem with returning 404 page after published.

Answer (score 1):

This is how your `firebase.json` should look like, this way all routes will be redirected to your React app `ìndex.html` and from there you control routing with your app router.

```
"hosting": {
  "rewrites": [{
    "source": "**",
    "destination": "/index.html"
  }]
}
```

Offical Firebase documentation on rewrites:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#rewrites

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap your Routes in router like this.

```
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  Redirect
} from "react-router-dom";
```

```
<Router> // this is required
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          <Redirect to="/" />
        </Switch>
</Router> // this is required
```

Comment: Oh I have that in my index.js file. is it better To move the browserRouter into App.js?

Comment: Yes.
I am doing similar application now and everything works fine for me without additional firebase configs I think there is something wrong in front end. But check your firebase hosting also.

Comment: would it possible to share what did you do to the host section in your firebase.json?

Comment: I only changed deploy folder to "build"
{
"firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": [
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run lint",
      "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
    ]
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  }
}